# Access violation when embedding Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, embed

I need help understanding why embedded Python is crashing in this extremely simple test case on Windows.

This works great:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <Python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#endif

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"Hello world!\")");
    return 0;
}
```

This crashes with an access violation:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <Python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#endif

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << Py_GetPythonHome() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My research has led me [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx). I determined that my python installation (2.6.5) is compiled to use `msvcr90.dll` and the embedding program uses `msvcr100.dll`.

The first thing that grabbed my attention was that `Py_GetPythonHome()` surely checks environment variables, one of the flagged problems of having multiple MS C runtimes used in a single application. However according to the MSDN example, I should only expect the environment variable values to be out of synch, not to cause an access violation.

Please help me understand!

Comment: Have you tried recompiling Python with MSVC 2010 (which uses the msvcr100.dll runtime library)?  Or have you tried compiling it in as a static library instead of as a DLL?

Comment: I'm not sure how feasible that is for me. I just grabbed the 2.6.7 source and all the included MSVC solutions were unable to be converted by MSVC 2010. I don't know yet if older versions will have more up to date MSVC projects or if I'll be able to manually set up the compilation yet.